# Android equivalent of IOS App-Groups functionality

Tags: android, ios

Is there anything equivalent of ios app groups for interprocess communication and sharing data?

I know android has Content Provider, but that is not the same thing.

**Ios app groups**:

> App groups allow multiple apps produced by a single development team to access shared containers and communicate using interprocess communication (IPC). Apps may belong to one or more app groups.

link: [apple.docs.app.groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups)

**Android content provider**:

> Content providers are Android’s central mechanism that enables you to access data of other applications – mostly information stored in databases or flat files. As such content providers are one of Android’s central component types to support the modular approach common to Android. Without content providers accessing data of other apps would be a mess.

link: [android.docs.content.provider](https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-content-providers)

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate via IPC over BroadcastReceivers and via ContentProviders.  If you want to share files, any apps signed with the same key can access each other's files.  Broadcasts and ContentProviders can be tied to permissions to keep other apps out

Comment: And what if I want to have one database to be shared between those apps, and none of the app to be the owner of the database? So if you delete the app, database would not be deleted as long as 'app group exist', like for ios, and they all can use the database?

Comment: Honestly I'd be suggesting you reconsider why you have separate apps, if they're sharing a db.  It sounds more like you have 1 app with multiple top level activities, and you should treat it as such.

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but we already have apps for ios, there is a good explanation why do we need that, works as a charm on ios. Now we want the same thing on android, but there are a few obstacles

Comment: What you want doesn't exist.  You might be able to find workarounds, but you'll be fighting an uphill battle.  My best suggestion would be one central app that owns all of the data so the other apps can be added and removed at will.

Comment: We also thought about that, but what when you delete that app, will the database be lost?

Comment: Yes, when you delete an app all files in its private storage are deleted with the app.  That's going to be an unavoidable problem.  There is no "don't delete this file if these other apps are still installed" functionality.

Comment: Also thought about external storage, but than user will be prompted to allow that or not, or if that would be an SD card, which can be unmounted... So too many problems :)

Comment: Maybe with this question android community will start thinking about that, in future :)

Comment: extenral storage != SD card.  They're separate concepts.  Its a bit weird.  But I wouldn't expect to see this functionality added anytime soon.  Honestly, the number of times you install more than 1 app by the same company are extremely tiny.  And generally when you are you're talking a corporate device, in which case you can just ban uninstall by policy

Comment: Understood, thank you very much for your help. I would leave the question here, those comments are very helpful.

Comment: Good discussion. I have had the same requirement and was just re-researching if anything has changed in this regard. As mentioned there is an answer in iOS. Windows/UWP also has the same basic functionality as iOS in this regard. So it's Android where the workarounds are needed. It's a problem that more likely applies to users of an enterprise suite of mobile apps that share a core db but the user can pick and choose which apps apply to their specific mobile situation.